# Orthogonal Orientation

Tags: code-golf, string

**Task:** Given an input consisting of exactly one of the characters `<>^v`, output a second input consisting of the printable ASCII characters (from space to tilde), oriented with the arrow.

Let's assume the second input to the program is `ABC`. This is what it should do:

- Input `>`: print `ABC`.
- Input `<`: print `CBA`.
- Input `^`: print `C\nB\nA`, or the input rotated -90°.
- Input `v`: print `A\nB\nC`, or the input rotated 90°.

### Test cases

```
input => \n output
---
">", "thanks!" =>
thanks!
---
"<", "Hello, World!" =>
!dlroW ,olleH
---
"^", "This is text." =>
.
t
x
e
t

s
i

s
i
h
T
---
"v", "Tokyo" =>
T
o
k
y
o
---
"<", ">>>" =>
>>>
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Full code or function?

Comment: @AlexL. You can write either afaik

Comment: Is input all as one string OK? `>ABC`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yes, that's fine.

Comment: No, I'm implying that it doesn't matter. You have no test case for the `>` orientation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>10</s> 6 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to Martin!*

```
19\qX!
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTlccVgh&input=J14nCidUaGlzIGlzIHRleHQn)

```
19\            % implicitly take input (a character) and compute mod-19 of its ASCII code
   q           % subtract 1. Gives 17, 2, 3, 4 for the characters '^<v>' respectively.
               % These numbers correspond to 1, 2, 3, 4 modulo 4, and so are the numbers
               % of 90-degree rotations required by each character
    X!         % implicitly take input (string). Rotate the computed number of times
               % in steps of 90 degrees. Implicitly display
```

---

Old version, without modulo operations: 10 bytes

```
'^<v>'=fX!
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=J148dj4nPWZYIQ&input=J14nCidUaGlzIGlzIHRleHQn)

```
'^<v>'         % push string
      =        % implicitly take input (a char) and test for equality
       f       % find index of matching character
        X!     % implicitly take input (string). Rotate that number of times
               % in steps of 90 degrees. Implicitly display
```

Comment: Damn I was really proud of my 13 bytes, but needing 3 bytes for input and 6 for rotating... oh well... maybe you can also save something with the `mod 11` trick (you'll have to rotate the other way round though).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Good idea! In my case (in yours?) I think mod 19 is better, because then subtracting 1 directly gives 1,2,3,4 (mod 4). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: 4 bytes shorter, what on earth...

Comment: I am officially putting MATL on the "list of language that are insanely short."

Answer (score 12):

### Python 3, <s>64</s> <s>51</s> 48 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to xnor.

Saved 7 bytes thanks to Lynn.

Saved 3 bytes thanks to DSM and Morgan from **so**python.

```python
lambda c,s:'\n'[c<'?':].join(s[::1|-(c in'<^')])
```

The function accepts one of the characters from `<>^v` as the first argument and the string that needs to be rotated as the second argument.

---

Here's a more readable version:

```
lambda c, s: ('\n' if c in '^v' else '').join(s[::-1 if c in'<^' else 1])
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! If it helps, you are allowed to take two separate inputs as well. (Me not knowing python, this is just a guess.)

Comment: Maybe `s[1|-(c in'<^')]` and `sep='\n'*(c in'^v')`

Comment: I think you could do the whole thing as a `lambda` if you use `join` with your sep rather than printing.

Comment: Why did you make it cw?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ: Because why not? There's a big room for improvement, as demonstrated in comments above. I'm not willing to get reputation for implementing other people's suggestions (even if it's acceptable). Also, CW encourages edits.

Comment: I love this answer, this is my favourite answer.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 57 bytes

```
f">"=id
f"<"=reverse
f"v"=init.((:"\n")=<<)
f _=f"<".f"v"
```

Usage example: `f "v" "ABC"` -> `"A\nB\nC"`.

Direction `>` is the idendity function, `<` reverses it's argument, `v` appends a newline to each character in the string and drops the last one and `^` is `v` followed by `<`.

Answer (score 6):

## Japt, 9 bytes

```
VzUc %B+1
```

Inspired by @DonMuesli's answer, although I just noticed the CJam one uses exactly the same technique. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VnpVYyAlQisx&input=Il4iICJBQkMi)

#### How it works

```
           // Implicit: U = arrow char, V = text
  Uc %B    // Take the char code of U, mod 11.
           // This converts ">", "v", "<", and "^" to 7, 8, 5, and 6, respectively.
Vz     +1  // Add one and rotate V by 90° clockwise that many times.
```

Comment: o_o nice job! You outgolfed jolf by over 200% o_O

Comment: But I'm getting errors? `Error: Japt.stdout must be sent to an HTMLElement` etc.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Not sure why that happens, but it happens a lot >:( Reloading always fixes this for me.

Comment: Sure enough, the issue is fixed. I am impressed!

Comment: I knew those rotate functions would eventually be useful +1

Comment: Same here. Error, then it works

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, <del>17</del> 15

```
jWgz\^_W}z"<^"w
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jWgz%5C%5E_W%7Dz%22%3C%5E%22w&input=%5E%0AHello%2C+World%21&debug=0) or run the [Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jWgz%5C%5E_W%7Dz%22%3C%5E%22w&input=%5E%0AHello%2C+World%21&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%3C%0AHello%2C+World%21%0A%5E%0AThis+is+text.%0Av%0ATokyo%0A%3C%0A%3E%3E%3E&debug=0&input_size=2)

2 bytes saved thanks to Jakube!

Alternatively using mod tricks:

```
@s_MBjBz)h%Cw11
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40s_MBjBz%29h%25Cw11&input=Hello%2C%20World%21%0A%3C&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, 13 bytes

```
l(iB%{W%z}*N*
```

Input is the orientation character followed directly by the string to be rotated.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l(iB%25%7BW%25z%7D*N*&input=%3EABC)

#### Explanation

Yay for modulo magic. Taking the four characters modulo 11 maps them to:

```
> 7 
v 8 
< 5
^ 6
```

These are all distinct modulo 4 and more importantly they are neatly increasing: `3, 0, 1, 2`. That means we can just use the result of the `mod 11` to determine how often to rotate (without needing an explicit `mod 4`, since four rotations are a no-op anyway). We'd normally have to offset these numbers by 1, such that `>` actually yields `8` and becomes a no-op, but the way I'm rotating them, actually reverses the string on the first application such that we always get one rotation for free.

```
l    e# Read input.
(i   e# Pull off the first character and convert to its character code.
B%   e# Modulo 11.
{    e# That many times...
 W%  e#   Reverse... on the first iteration this reverses the string. Afterwards
     e#   we'll have an Nx1 or 1xN grid of characters on the stack, where
     e#   this reverses the rows instead.
 z   e#   Transpose. On the first iteration, this simply wraps the string in
     e#   array, turning it into a grid without changing its orientation further
     e#   beyond the reversal that just happened. On subsequent iterations, a
     e#   transpose combined with reversing the rows rotates the grid 90 degrees
     e#   clockwise.
}*
N*   e# Join with linefeeds.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 51 bytes

```
f(d,s)=join(d∈"<^"?reverse(s):s,d∈"^v"?"\n":"")
```

This is a function that accepts a `Char` and a string and returns a string.

Let `d` be the character denoting the direction and `s` be the string. If `d` is left or up, we use the reverse of `s`, otherwise we use `s` as given. We construct a separator as the empty string if `d` is left or right, or a newline if `d` is up or down. The pass the string and the separator to `join`, which will insert the separator between each character of the string and return a string.

[Verify all test cases online](http://goo.gl/50zYRB)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>76</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```
(a,b)=>(/v|>/.test(a)?[...b]:[...b].reverse()).join(a>`>`?`
`:``)
```

Port of @Alex A.'s Julia answer. Edit: Saved 9 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions. Saved two bytes separately thanks to @edc65.

Comment: `/[v^]/.test(a)` => `'Z'<a`

Comment: +1 ?"reverse":"slice" genius

Comment: @edc65 Whoops, I accidentally copied an old version; the boring `?:` version was 1 byte shorter.

Comment: `(/v|>/.test(a)?[...b]:[...b].reverse())...` should be 65

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU Utilities, 67

```bash
(egrep -q '>|v'<<<$1&&cat||rev)|(egrep -q '<|>'<<<$1&&cat||fold -1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed you need a space after the `-q`'s, but you do

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>54</s> 51 + 1 = 52 bytes

```
@.=<>=~/./g;@.=reverse@.if/[<^]/;$,=$/x/[v^]/;say@.
```

Requires the `-n` flag and the free `-M5.010`|`-E`. Takes input as the following: `direction\nline`:

```
$ perl -nE'@.=<>=~/./g;@.=reverse@.if/[<^]/;$,=$/x/[v^]/;say@.' <<< $'^\nhello'
o
l
l
e
h
```

I like that `$/x/[v^]/` looks like a substitution.

How it works:

```
                                                    # -n read first line into $_
@.=<>=~/./g;                                        # Read next line and split
            @.=reverse@.if/[<^]/;                   # Reverse `@.` if matches 
                                                    # `<` or `^`
                                 $,=                # An array will be concatena-
                                                    # ted with the value of 
                                                    # `$,` when printed. 
                                     $/             # Contains a newline
                                        /[v^]/      # boolean 
                                       x            # "\n" x 1 -> "\n"
                                                    # "\n" x 0 -> ""
                                              say@. # Print the array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 60 bytes

Needs golfing...

```
$
¶
+`^([<^].*)(.)(¶.*)
$1$3$2
¶

.
$&¶
+`([<>].*)¶
$1
^.¶?
```

Input is all as one string, e.g. `^ABC`.

- If `^` or `<`, reverse the string
- Insert newlines after every character
- If `<` or `>`, remove the newlines

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JArCtgorYF4oWzxeXS4qKSguKSjCti4qKQokMSQzJDIKwrYKCi4KJCbCtgorYChbPD5dLiopwrYKJDEKXi7Ctj8K&input=XkFCQw)

Comment: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JArCtgorYF4oWzxeXS4qKSguKSjCti4qKQokMSQzJDIKwrYKCk0hYC4KK2AoWzw-XS4qKcK2CiQxCl4uwrY_Cg&input=XkFCQw saves a byte (and gets rid of the additional trailing linefeed)

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 84 bytes

```
param([char]$a,$b)($b[($c=$b.length)..0],$b[0..$c])[$a%7-eq6]-join("","`n")[90-lt$a]
```

This is going to be complete gibberish to people not familiar with PowerShell. Let's go through it.

Takes input `param([char]$a,$b)`, with an explicit cast to character for `$a`. The rest of the program is one statement. We'll start with the first half, up to the `-join`.

We're creating a new dynamic array `(...,...)` and indexing into it with `$a%7-eq6`. The ASCII values for `v` and `>` are `116` and `62`, respectively, and `116%7 = 62%7 = 6`, and those are the two directions that "increase" down and to the right. So, if that `-eq` is `$true`, we'll take the second value, which is `$b[0..$c]`, or *an array of the characters of `$b` up to the end*. We get the value `$c` from the first value, `$b[($c=$b.length)..0]`, which gets selected if the input char is `^` or `<` (i.e., so it goes through the string backwards). Important to note is that even if the second value is selected, the `$c` value is still calculated and stored, so we can re-use it as a shortcut like this.

So, we've now got an array of characters either going forwards or backwards. We then `-join` those characters together with the result of another dynamic array index. This time we're selecting based on whether the ASCII value for `$a` is below `90` (really lots of values would work, I selected this one just because). Since `>` and `<` both have a value below `90`, the `-lt` is `$false`, so we select the empty string `""`, and thus the char-array is simply concatenated. Otherwise, we select the newline character `` "`n" `` to join the char-array together with newlines.

This resultant string is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

**Example**

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\orthogonal-orientation.ps1 "^" "TimmyD"
D
y
m
m
i
T
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 15 bytes

```
⌽∘⍉⍣(11|⎕UCS⍞)⍪
```

`⍪` make string into 1-column table
`⍣(‍`…`)` repeat (*n*) times
`⍞` get string input
`⎕UCS` convert to UCS code point
`11|` division rest when divided by 11
`⌽∘⍉` rotate -90° (flip-transpose)

Alternate method (same length):

```
⌽∘⍉⍣('<^>v'⍳⎕)⍪
```

`⎕` get evaluated input (so one must input, e.g. '^' or the name of a program/variable that returns the desired character)
`'<^>v'⍳` index into the string

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>123</s> <s>119</s> <s>117</s> 114 bytes

Golfed:

```c
f(char*d,char*a){char*b=a,c=*d%21,s[3]={0,c&8?10:0};while(*++b);while(*s=c&4?*a++:*--b)printf(s);if(c&16)puts(b);}
```

Test program, with explanations & somewhat ungolfed code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// c     c%21   
// <    10010     => if(c&8), vertical; if(c&16), horizontal
// >    10100     => if(c&4), backwards
// ^    01010
// v    01101
int f(char*d,char*a){
    char *b=a,c=*d%21,s[3]={0,c&8?10:0};
    while(*++b);     // b = a + strlen(a) - 1; this is shorter
    while(*s=c&4?*a++:*--b)printf(s);
    if(c&16)puts(b); // single trailing newline if horizontal
}

int main() {
    char *c="<>^v";
    for(;*c;c++) { 
        printf("--- %c ---\n", *c); 
        f(c,"hello world!"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tips welcome!

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY/disIwEIXvfYoxYMhPA/4sIo5ZX2RZSKftKsRUkupeSJ@9xrCL52I@OHOGw5Ah78LPNCXsBJ1cVE1V4OSjsLZOpyH6NggnK7KqWaxX2PVRYLLEP47Kab1XxtR4jecwdIInKZO2gvhOqs16icRXW86vtyGJWuI45RRc3DkICY8ZZL2KQJFlh8/vO8PilQZFSFrnGBTvpb8SZoyBBUHGV2BVvpb4DuVXKnZqve/ht4@@mbP/7VhmbIdbDLDE2Tg9AQ "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
zVc %BÄ
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=elZjICVCxA&input=IkFCQyIKIl4i)

Comment: How? Does Japt have some kind of rotation builtin?

Comment: @emanresuA, yep, that's the `z` method here; rotates a string `90°*[argument]`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>91</s> <s>83</s> 84 bytes

```
(a,b)=>[b,(c=[...b].reverse()).join``,[...b].join`
`,c.join`
`]["><v^".indexOf‌​(a)]
```

Constructs the necessary strings and obtains the index of which `a` lies in. `indexOf` is used because `^` is a regex token. Thanks to ETHproductions for the bug fix and shaved bytes!

Comment: `f("v","abc")` returns `c\nb\na` for me.

Comment: Here's an 84-byte one that works for me: ```(a,b)=>[b,(c=[...b].reverse()).join``,[...b].join`\n`,c.join`\n`]["><v^".indexOf(a)]```

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks! I forgot `c` is literally `d`.

Comment: Out of interest I tried indexing an object... and it turned out to be exactly the same length!

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 22 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=LuKAmElfSc6zwp9HSUVfzrPigJkgaSI-PHZeImk) You should replace `ƒ` with `\x9f`. Takes the sting, then the directional character.

```
.‘I_IγƒGIE_γ’ i"><v^"i
 ‘                      golfy array
  I                     the input
   _I                   input reversed
      ƒGIE              split by "" and join by newlines
     γ                  γ = that
          _γ            gamma reversed
.            _i"><v^"i  get the respective index
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 67 bytes

66 plus one for `-p`

```
$_=reverse if/^[<^]/;$&?s/.$//:s/.//;$&=~/[v^]/&&s/(.)(?=.)/$1\n/g
```

The input is a single string whose first character defines the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6) 71

```js
(a,b)=>([...b].map(c=>(a>'A'?c+=`
`:0,r=/v|>/.test(a)?r+c:c+r),r=''),r)
```

**Test**

```js
F=(a,b)=>([...b].map(c=>(a>'A'?c+=`
`:0,r=/v|>/.test(a)?r+c:c+r),r=''),r)  

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n';

for(d of '<>^v') console.log(d+'\n'+F(d,'ABCDE')+'\n')
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## D, 198 bytes

```
import std.stdio,std.array,std.algorithm;void main(string[]a){auto x=a[2].split("");char[]y;if(canFind(["^","<"],a[1]))x.reverse;if(canFind(["v","^"],a[1]))y=x.join("\n");else y=x.join("");y.write;}
```

:c

---

Less golfed:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.array;
import std.algorithm;

void main(string[]a) {
    
  auto x=a[2].split("");
  string y;

  if(canFind(["^","<"],a[1]))
    x.reverse;

  if(canFind(["v","^"], a[1]))
    y=join(x,"\n");

  else
    y=join(x,"");

  y.write;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 48 bytes

```
[`5/%$$a:4<&[1$][1_]?\1-[$;$][,^+a;2>['
,][]?]#]
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda that takes both argument and STDIN input. Usage:

```
0"asdf"[`5/%$$a:4<&[1$][1_]?\1-[$;$][,^+a;2>['
,][]?]#]! {make sure to put one of <>^v in STDIN}
```

## Explanation

```
[                                               ] {lambda}
 `5/%$$a:                                         {store STDIN char (mod 5) to a}
         4<&                                      {is 0<a<4?}
            [  ][  ]?                             {conditional}
             1$                                     {if so, push 2 1's}
                 1_                                 {otherwise, push -1}
                                                    {determines whether to output in reverse or not}
                     \1-                          {swap, -1}
                        [   ][                ]#  {while loop}
                         $;$                        {if there is a char at index}
                              ,                     {output that char}
                               ^+                   {increment/decrement index}
                                 a;2>               {check if a>2}
                                     [    ][]?      {conditional}
                                      '\n,          {if so, output newline}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 41 bytes

```
,' 9uc#;+"? R #'{}j #R'{}j"fs,"><v^"í@E£ƒ
```

Takes the string as the first input and the direction (`><v^`) as the second input.

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LCcgOXVjIzsrIj8gUiAjJ3t9aiAjUid7fWoiZnMsIj48dl4iw61ARcKjxpI&input=IkFCQyIKPA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
C:½›₃[√⌈₂ßṘ⁋|₃ßṘ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=C%3A%C2%BD%E2%80%BA%E2%82%83%5B%E2%88%9A%E2%8C%88%E2%82%82%C3%9F%E1%B9%98%E2%81%8B%7C%E2%82%83%C3%9F%E1%B9%98&inputs=%3E%0AHello&header=&footer=)

```
C:               # Get charcode, dupe for later use
  ½›₃[           # If C/2 + 1 %  3 == 0 (`^v`)...
      √⌈₂        # Is ceil(√C) is even?
         ßṘ      # If so, reverse
           ⁋     # Join by newlines
            |    # Else...
             ₃   # Is C divisible by 3?
              ßṘ # If so, reverse
```